# Plotting point perpendicular to line half way through cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a line that is plotted between two points. Lets say A and B, I can grab the mid point of the line in Cocos2d really easily and I also can calculate the vector and the perpendicular vector to this line quite easily. However my math skills are very rusty and I have no idea how to do the following.

Lets say the distance between A and B is 50, so the midpoint is 25. I would like to plot a point that is perpendicular to this line with a distance of 10 away from it.

```
      C
     /  \
    /    \
   /      \
  /        \
 /          \
A------------B
```

Sorry for the terrible example, but I'm not sure how to do this. Also the AB line is always at some angle, it's never straight like it is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the midpoint `m` and the perpendicular vector `v`, you need to normalize `v` and then move in the direction of `v` from `m`. So something like this:

```
Vector2d nv = v / v.length(); // Assuming Vector2d is your vector class and length gives the length of v
Point2d newPoint = m + (nv * 10.0); // Assumes you can multiply a vector by a scalar
```

If you aren't working in C++, you may have to write it manually like this:

```
Vector2d nv;
nv.x = v.x / v.length();
nv.y = v.y / v.length();
newPoint.x = m.x + nv.x * 10.0;
newPoint.y = m.y + nv.y * 10.0;
```